# Query with function inside is not using an index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query like this:

```
SELECT f.id_foo
FROM foo f
WHERE date_trunc('day'::text, current_date - '597 days'::interval) > date_trunc('day'::text, f.my_date);
```

And it is working as I suppose it should. It is using an `date_trunc_index`:

```
CREATE INDEX date_trunc_index
ON foo
USING btree
(date_trunc('day'::text, my_date));
```

Let's assume that this query is inside other function/query/view and I want to control number of days via function `get_days()` which returns `interval`

My query will look like:

```
SELECT f.id_foo
FROM foo f
WHERE date_trunc('day'::text, current_date - get_days()) > date_trunc('day'::text, f.my_date);
```

My question is: why 2nd query is not using `date_trunc_index` anymore? And how to fix that?

**EDIT**

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for:

1st query:

```
"Index Scan using date_trunc_index on foo f  (cost=0.01..8.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (date_trunc('day'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date - '597 days'::interval)) > date_trunc('day'::text, my_date))"
"Total runtime: 0.049 ms"
```

2nd query:

```
"Seq Scan on foo f  (cost=0.00..4228786.45 rows=2993719 width=8) (actual time=56384.159..56384.159 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (date_trunc('day'::text, (('now'::cstring)::date - get_days())) > date_trunc('day'::text, my_date))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 8980835"
"Total runtime: 56384.181 ms"
```

Comment: What `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` says?

Comment: @icuken updated with 2 `explain analyze` results

Comment: Is `get_days()` declared as "IMMUTABLE" or "STABLE"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff So obvious... It was declared as `VOLATILE`. Changing it to `STABLE` fix everything. Can you post your comment as answer, to let me accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has three important characteristics of functions that are used for optimizing queries:  immutable, stable, and volatile functions.

The first two are "constant" during a single run of a query.  That means that the optimizer can treat them as a constant.  A volatile function -- such as `random()` -- returns a different value each time it is called.

These are explained in the `create function` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html).